# Incorrect output with getGenericReturnType on Java 8

Tags: java, reflection

I get a strange result for a specific reflection call using Java 8 (JDK 1.8.0_71) and Mockito (version 2.0.44-beta).

Calling the following:

```
BDDMockito.class.getMethod("given", Object.class).getGenericReturnType().getTypeName()
```

gives this erroneous result:

```
org.mockito.BDDMockito.org.mockito.BDDMockito$BDDMyOngoingStubbing<T>
```

This does not look right (the package does not exist), and I have not seen this problem with other Java classes or with other methods of BDDMockito. I think the result should be:

```
org.mockito.BDDMockito$BDDMyOngoingStubbing<T>
```

Is there an explanation for the result I got?  Is this a known issue or should I report it to Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. It has been reported in the ticket [JDK-8054213](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054213) and is currently unresolved for all versions (including the current JDK 9 beta).

Note that you can reproduce it with a simpler example. The problem comes with the usage of an nested class as a method return type. `getGenericReturnType` incorrectly repeats the class name in the output. This is reproducible with a static nested class or an inner class.

```
package parent;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Main.class.getMethod("bar").getGenericReturnType());
        // prints "parent.Main.parent.Main$Bar<T>"
    }

    public <T> Bar<T> bar() {
        return null;
    }

    /*static*/ class Bar<T> {}

}
```

Comment: That's so frustrating. It was reported in 2014. It's [right here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/reflect/generics/reflectiveObjects/ParameterizedTypeImpl.java#223). Line 223 uses `getName()` instead of `getSimpleName()`.